# C# How to keep do-while loop asking the same question until enter pressed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, constructor

I am a beginner in C# programming and trying to code an app that reads the user input using a do-while loop, however, the loop doesn't continue executing when the user answers the question. I only want the loop to stops when enter is pressed

This is what I have done so far

Thanks in advance!

```
    //call method to read a text, calculate and display the num of chars

    private void ShowStringLength() {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Let me calculate the length of strings for you!");
            Console.WriteLine("Give me text of any length, or press ENTER to exit!");

            Console.Write("Enter a string : ");
            String str = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(str.ToUpper());
            int len = str.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Numer of Chars is : " + len);

            //Reads “Enter” from the keyboard to exit the app

            cki = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Write("OK. You pressed Enter. See you agian!");
        } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this small app?

Comment: When the user presses `Enter` without entering any text, your computed `len` will be zero. So you could change the loop to a `while (true)` loop which you exit via an `if (len == 0) break;` condition.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thank you Matthew, it worked with the if condition, however, I'm still getting this:

Give me text of any length, or press ENTER to exit!

Enter a string :

Numer of Chars is : 0

OK. You pressed Enter. See you again!

I down want it to continue count when enter is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The `cki = Console.ReadKey();` waits for any key input, not just *enter*. This makes the text *"OK. You pressed Enter. See you agian!"* show even if you actually pressed another key.

You could instead check the entered string, and exit the loop if it is empty. Example:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Let me calculate the length of strings for you!");
    Console.WriteLine("Give me text of any length, or press ENTER to exit!");

    Console.Write("Enter a string : ");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();

    // If the string is null, empty or only contains white spaces,
    // break out of the loop.
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    {
        Console.Write("OK. You pressed Enter. See you agian!");
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(str.ToUpper());
    Console.WriteLine("Numer of Chars is : " + str.Length);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can now exit the loop, however, the app still counts the length like this: 

Numer of Chars is : 0


I don't actually want it to continue counting when enter is pressed. I just want the app to print out the enter message: "OK. You pressed Enter. See you agian!"

Comment: The app does not print out the "Number of Chars is: 0" after the enter-press if you have used the example. Copy-paste and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
if(Console.KeyAvailable)
{
  cki = console.ReadKey();
  ...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
private void ShowStringLength()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Let me calculate the length of strings for you!");
        Console.WriteLine("Give me text of any length, or press ENTER to exit!");

        Console.Write("Enter a string : ");
        String str = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToUpper());
        int len = str.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Numer of Chars is : " + len);

        //Reads “Enter” from the keyboard to exit the app
        cki = Console.ReadKey();
        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            Console.Write("OK. You pressed Enter. See you agian!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(); //To start with a clean line
        }
    } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code to made what you ant and  i added a character ;in this sample space;
to determine that the string is finished. then calculated the length of string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit... ");
            var outPutString = "";
            var list = new List<int>();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Let me calculate the length of strings for you!");
                Console.WriteLine("Give me text of any length, or press ENTER to exit!");
                Console.Write("Enter a string End with space : ");
                var readKey = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                if (readKey == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"Length of {outPutString} is : {(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outPutString) ? 0 : outPutString.Length)}");
                    break;
                }

                while (readKey != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                {
                    if (readKey == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            $"Length of {outPutString} is : {(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outPutString) ? 0 : outPutString.Length)}");
                        break;
                    }

                    var result = ((int) readKey);
                    list.Add(result);
                    outPutString = list.Aggregate(outPutString, (current, item) => current + (char) item);

                    list.Clear();
                   
                    readKey = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Length of {outPutString} is : {(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outPutString) ? 0 : outPutString.Length)}");
                outPutString = "";


            }
        }
    }
}
```